# Excel query group by column value and count distinct text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following data.

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | X |
| A | X |
| A | Y |
| A | Y |
| A | Y |
| A | N |
| B | Z |
| B | Z |
| B | V |

I need to out as following. Col 2 is count of distinct text.

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| B | 2 |

I have use following equation in google sheet but it is not count distinct text.

```
=QUERY(Client!C3:E1000, "select C, count(E) group by C")
```

Above formula given following data

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 6 |
| B | 3 |

Comment: why are you tagging this as excel and also adding excel to the title of your question if you mentioned you are using google sheets to do the calculations? each program uses slightly different formulas and syntax

Answer (score 0):

You should be counting the DISTINCT values on your grouped data.

Instead of using COUNT, you should use COUNTUNIQUE

```
=QUERY(Client!C3:E1000, "select C, COUNTUNIQUE(E) group by C")
```